# Refining output of a curl command

Tags: shell, curl

I have an output of a curl command as below,

comand:  curl https://application.com/api/projectcreator

Output:

```
{"Table":[{"key":"projectA","name":"Jhon"},
          {"key":"projectB","name":"Sam"},
          {"key":"ProjectC","name":"Jack"}]}
```

I would like to cut this output to get only names. is there a way to do this in shell?

Eg: 
Jhon
Sam
Jack

I tried below but doesnt seem to be promissing for me.

```
for Table in `curl -s -k http://application.com/api/projectcreator grep "name"`
do
   echo "$Table"
done
```

Thanks for your help and insights!

Comment: Can you use `jq` ?

Comment: @anubhava we can, but shell is prefered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jq` you can do this easily:

```
curl -s -k 'http://application.com/api/projectcreator' |
jq -r '.Table[].name' | paste -s -d ' '
```

```
Jhon Sam Jack
```

If `jq` cannot be installed then use `gnu grep`:

```
curl -s -k 'http://application.com/api/projectcreator' |
grep -oP '"name":"\K[^"]+' | paste -s -d ' '
```